# cvWaitKey() is not working?

Tags: c, opencv

I'm reading a book. The author explains the function clearly. The problem is that my program doesn't detect any key that is pressed, so I can't terminate the window or stop a loop. This is the part of the problem.

```
 while(1)
    {   
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if ( !frame ) 
            break;
        cvShowImage("Example2", frame);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if ( c == 27 ) 
        {   
            printf("Yes");
            break; // 27 == escape button
        }
    }
```

I'm using Mac (I'm running the program from the terminal).

Comment: When you use `cvWaitKey(X)`, the program waits for **X** milliseconds for your to press the key. You aren't giving it enough time to detect the key press. Refer to [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=cvwaitkey#waitkey) for details.

Comment: @scap3y, the `if ( c == 27 )` doesn't work at all even if I increase the delay time. This is why I put `"Yes"` to indicate that I have pressed the button. I've set it as `cvWaitKey(10000)` with no hope. This is why I'm shocked with this trivial stuff that doesn't work properly.

Comment: @CroCo have you tried exit() instead of break?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava, yes but still not working.

Comment: @CroCo so it keeps on displaying and the window is not being closed, yes?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava, exactly.

Comment: In the terminal, I type `./test mars.avi` After if I press escape button, it shows me `^[`

Comment: Is the program outputting `Yes` or no output at all?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava, no it doesn't. This is why I'm shocked with this very simple function.

Comment: @CroCo This has worked for me in the past. I mean all the time. I guess you can try changing the platform and then trying it again. Never have had to face this error. Sorry.

Comment: You have to press a key when "Example2" window is focused. Are you doing that or pressing a key when terminal is focused?

Comment: what u actual want? plz give clear idea

Comment: @guneykayim, damnnnnnnnnnnnn you hit me upside the head. It worked however, it doesn't print `Yes` Why?

Comment: What do you mean it worked but does not print Yes? Loop broke but did not print Yes? Are you sure? Maybe window is closed fast and you don't see it? try to place pause?

Comment: @guneykayim, the program is console, so I'm assuming if I hit `ESC`, then the `if ( c == 27 )` should work and it does. It terminates the the window but in the terminal there is no `Yes`.

Comment: Can you print anything else from another line in your code?

Comment: @guneykayim, I messed up sorry for that. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be 2 possibilities ,

- The focus is not on the cv window when you press the key.
- Try using just, cvWaitKey().

Comment: cvWaitKey() is equal to cvWaitKey(0), so just waiting until a key is pressed.